# is there a better way? new to c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ but do have a basic knowledge in coding. This program works fine and well but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

The program makes a star wars name by taking the first three letters of your last name and the first 2 of your first name to make your first name of your star wars name. Then for your star wars surname it takes the first two letters of your mother's maiden name and the first three letters of the city you were born in.

```
// starWarsName.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string firstName; 
    string surname; 
    string maidenName;
    string city;
    cout << "This program is designed to make you a star wars name, it takes some information and concatinates parts of the information to make your NEW name" <<endl << endl;

    cout << "please enter your first name" << endl;
    cin >> firstName;
    cout << "please enter your surname" <<endl;
    cin >> surname; 
    cout << "what is your mothers maiden name?" << endl;
    cin >> maidenName;
    cout << "please tel me which city you were born in" << endl;
    cin >> city; 

    cout << firstName << " " << surname << endl;
    cout << firstName[0] << " " << surname << endl;

    int size = firstName.length();
    //cout << size;
    cout << surname[0] << surname[1] << surname[2] << firstName[0] << firstName[1];
    cout << " " << maidenName[0] << maidenName[1] << city[0] << city[1] << city[2];

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, not used stack exchange enough to know what to do.

Comment: Well, you do now...

Comment: The immediate improve (not just in C++ but also when using other programming languages): **always** check if input was successful *after* the attempt to read input!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's code review

Answer (score 0):

You can use **string::substr** here to store character sequence instead of writing surname[0]..surname[2] again and again.

Here is an example of **string::substr**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
std::string str="We think in generalities, but we live in details.";
                                       // (quoting Alfred N. Whitehead)

std::string str2 = str.substr (3,5);     // "think"

std::size_t pos = str.find("live");      // position of "live" in str

std::string str3 = str.substr (pos);     // get from "live" to the end

std::cout << str2 << ' ' << str3 << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
think live in details.
```